# Перевод код Pascal на Java

Tags: java, pascal

Кто сможет перевести этот код с Pascal на Java прошу помочь.

```
uses crt;
var min,max,n,q,a:integer;
begin
    write ('Vvedite kolichestvo chisel v posledovatelnosti: '); 
    readln(n);
    write ('Vvedite posledovatelnost: '); 
    read(max); 
    min:=max;
    for q:=2 to n do 
        begin
            read(a);
            if a>max then max:=a;
            if a<min then min:=a;
        end;
    writeln;
    write ('Raznica: ',max-min);
end.
```

Comment: а что не получилось с переводом?

Comment: Когда уже допилят гуглопереводчик :D

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что здесь не переводят программы на другой язык без попыток автора.

Comment: С такими вопросами, лучше на фриланс писать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский или просто чтобы помочь не смотря на закрытые вопроса ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max, min;

    System.out.println("Введите количество чисел в последовательности ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int count = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Введите последовательность");
    int inputValue = sc.nextInt();

    max = inputValue;
    min = inputValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        inputValue = sc.nextInt();

        if(inputValue > max ) max = inputValue;
        if(inputValue < min ) min = inputValue;
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("Raznica = %s", max - min));
}
```

output:

```
Введите количество чисел в последовательности 
6
Введите последовательность
5
10
0
9
6
8
Raznica = 10
```